# Using biblatex in a document in catalan undesirable "urlalso: " text appears before links in references

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, babel

I have been using Overleaf for uni work for a couple of years now and I have had rarely any issues I couldn't solve. On this instance I have ran into an issue with my references.

I am using biblatex. I am working in catalan for this document. In my references, instead of getting the translated equivalent of "Available also from:" before the url i get "urlalso:". I have checked changing the language and this does not happen in, for example, spanish, for which " Disponible también desde:" appears perfectly normally.

Is there a way to edit the babel or biblatex package, whichever is causing this, to show a specific text before urls in the bibliography?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=iso-numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel} 
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @misc{bestplaceeu,
    month = {12},
    title = {{Best Places to Work in Europe 2023}},
    year = {2023},
    url = {https://bestplacestoworkfor.org/our-recent-lists/companies?id=53},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

Foo bar baz\cite{bestplaceeu}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Using "catalan" in babel package, undesirable "urlalso" text appears]

[image: Using "english" in babel package, undesirable "urlalso" does not text appear]

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. (We can't easily copy that code and it can also be an accessibility issue.). Instead mark it up as code. We also need to see the language and bibliography/citation setup of your document. So please show us a fully compilable example document that reproduces the issue with as little code as possible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Many thanks for the comments, I have now edited the question, included code and a hopefully clearer illustration of the problem.

Comment: From the duplicate: adding `\DefineBibliographyStrings{catalan}{
    urlalso = {Disponible també des de\addcolon}
}` produces the desired result.

Comment: Than you @Marijn , your suggestion solved the issue.